# SQL: Sort comments by votes and maintain threading

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my comments / votes schema/sample data: http://paste2.org/IkaXpcMt

Screenshots of the tables in phpmyadmin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgkwy.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/ketDI.png

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT cid, pid, thread, name, ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value), 0) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE entity_type = 'comment' AND entity_id = c.cid ) votes
FROM comment c
WHERE nid = 13852 AND status = 1
ORDER BY thread DESC, votes DESC
```

This maintains threading correctly, but as expected votes will never make a post go up in the order.

Current result:

[image: Current result]

The result I'm trying to achieve places CID 5 at the top, then 2, 26, 41, 22, 44, 42, 43, etc

So to clarify, comments of the same level must be sorted by votes, but their replies must come right after them following the same logic.

Replies have the PID (Parent ID) field set to the CID number of the parent.
So comments 44 and 42 are replies to comment 22. It's also easy to identify replies by the "thread" field. It describes in an easily sortable way the level/order of comments.

Comment: does your database support CONNECT BY and ORDER SIBLINGS BY clauses?

Comment: @Randy, apologies but I don't know. I'm using 5.5.34-MariaDB-1. EDIT: Apparently mysql has no support for either these clauses.

Comment: Can you be more precise on the ordering conditions you want to apply? You've listed the order that you want as result but it's not clear

Comment: Joël Salamin, I just edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me. I am not entirely certain what's the consequence of these subqueries on deeper comment levels, though.

```
SELECT cid, pid, thread, name, ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value), 0) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE entity_type = 'comment' AND entity_id = c.cid ) votes, ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value), 0) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE entity_type = 'comment' AND entity_id = IF(c.pid=0, c.cid, c.pid) ) top_level_vote
  FROM comment c
  WHERE nid = 13852 AND status = 1
  ORDER BY top_level_vote DESC, thread DESC
```